# Como usar o nome de uma célula da planilha Excel no VBA, para não indicar linha e coluna?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, declaração-de-variável

Como usar o nome de uma célula da planilha Excel no VBA, para não indicar linha e coluna?

Por exemplo, dei nome de "Nome_Cliente" à célula B20, quando uso esse nome no VBA para colocar no label ( label1.caption = Nome_Cliente ), ele aceita e não dá erro. Porém, não pega o valor da célula.

Como estou inserindo colunas e linhas, a célula muda, mas o VBA evidentemente não acerta as linhas e colunas do comando range.

Como faço para usar o nome da célula diretamente?

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quer, você quer pegar a coluna que acabou de incluir para poder alterar alguma propriedade dela?

Comment: Não expliquei direito. Nomeei uma célula no Excel e quero usar o nome definido no Excel como uma variável no VBA, para não precisar ficar alterando linha e coluna a cada mudança na planilha, é isso

Comment: Editei a resposta, essa seria minha melhor sugestão para você. Não acredito que seja possível fazer o que você quer em VBA

Comment: jbueno, pensei que fosse possível fazer algo assim, mas de forma indireta dá para fazer, apesar de dar mais trabalho. Grato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que você quer:
Você pega um Range, porque o nome não é chave primaria. Então roda todos os retornos dele.

```js
Sub Test()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set r = Range("Something")

    If r.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        For Each cell In r.Cells
            MsgBox cell.Value
        Next cell
    Else
        MsgBox r.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**ATUALIZANDO**

Não da para fazer isso em VB ou C#, ser fosse Python, por exemplo, você poderia.

Sugiro a criação de uma lista, alguma coisa assim:

```js
Dim dados As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
dados.Add("nome", "30/nome")
dados.Add("endereco", "30/endereco")
dados.Add("data_cnsc", "8/dt_nasc")
dados.Add("municipio", "20/municipio")
MessageBox.Show(dados("municipio"))'acessamos os valores por índices
```

Comment: Não expliquei direito.

Comment: Quero pegar o valor de uma célula no excel e usar como uma variável no VBA, assim se eu incluir linhas, usando o nome da célula o VBA usaria o mesmo valor da célula, não precisaria mexer no programa

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, vou tentar, eu usei o range("nome_da_celula").value como indicou anteriormente e funcionou também. Valeu

Comment: De nada, não deixa de marcar a resposta caso tenha atendido. Bom trabalho.

Comment: É a primeira vez que entro, cliquei na seta para cima, é isso?

Comment: E no check box em baixo das setas para dizer q é resposta, por favor.

Comment: ok, já fiz, obrigado

Comment: Eu votei na resposta porque ela tá bacana e correta. :) Mas, seria importante também colocar uma imagem indicando como/onde o nome do `range` é definido (campo na parte superior esquerda, antes de onde é exibida/editada a fórmula), só pra facilitar a vida de um futuro leitor que não conhece tanto do assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,
pela data da pergunta obviamente já deve ter achado uma solução.
Mas vou colocar aqui a solução que encontrei para ajudar mais gente.

Para acessar os atributos de um range que pode sair do lugar eu atribuí esse range nomeado a um objeto e agora utilizo o objeto nas referências no código:

```
Sub AcessandoRangeMovel()
    Dim endConsult1 As Object
    Dim endConsult2 As Object

    Set endConsult1 = Range("NomeConsultor1")
    Set endConsult2 = Range("NomeConsultor2")

    MsgBox endConsult1.Value
    MsgBox endConsult2.Address
End Sub
```